# Spring Boot EhCache: Storing a List of objects without a key

Tags: java, spring

I am using the @PostConstruct annotation on application start to query the entire list result from the DB and am storing it as a static global variable. I am parsing this result list and getting the responses I need. As shown below:

```
private static List<Object[]> allObjects;

@PostConstruct
     public void test() {
        System.out.println("Calling Method");
        Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query);
        List<Object[]> resultList = (List<Object[]>) q.getResultList();
        allObjects = resultList;
}
```

However, I would like to use ehcache to store the result list so I can refresh the cache at any time or remove the items from the cache. Is it possible to store a result list (without a key) in the cache instead of storing it as a global variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with spring boot than using [spring cache abstraction](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) is the most natural and recommended way for any caching needs (including with EhCache). It'll also solve the problem that you are trying to solve. Please setup the EhCacheManager as outlined in [Spring Boot Ehcache Example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-ehcache) article. Post this setup, separate the dbloading routine in a new bean and make it cache enabled. To pre-load the cache on startup, you can invoke this bean's method in any other bean's postconstruct. Following outline will give you fully working solution.

```
@Component
public class DbListProvider {

    @Cacheable("myDbList")
    public List<Object[]> getDbList() {
        System.out.println("Calling Method");
        Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query);
        List<Object[]> resultList = (List<Object[]>) q.getResultList();
        return resultList;
    }
}

// In your existing post construct method, just call this method to pre-load 
// these objects on startup Please note that you CAN NOT add this PostConstruct 
// method to DbListProvider as it will not trigger spring boot cache 
// abstraction responsible for managing and populating the cache
public class Myinitializer {
    @Autowired
    private DbListProvider listProvider;
    
    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        // load on startup 
        listProvider.getDbList();
    }
}
```

You can further inject DbListProvider bean anywhere in code base which gives you additional flexibility (should you need that).

You can use @CachePut, @CacheEvict as per your eviction policies without having to worry about EhCache behind the scene. I'll further recommend to understand all options available from spring cache and use them appropriately for your future needs. Following should help -

1. [A Guide To Caching in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial)
2. [Spring Cache Abstraction](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you so much for the information! Once I put the information in the cache, how would I retrieve the values, since it doesn't have a specific key? I would need to retrieve the result list from the cache.

Comment: that's the beauty of this abstraction, you don't have to interact with cache directly. You'll always be calling DbListProvider bean's getDbList() method and spring cache will ensure that actually execution do not take place beyond the first invocation. Essentially only first invocation will result in the code execution (which will be cached by spring), rest all invocation of this method will be intercepted by spring cache abstraction and it'll fetch result from ehcache instead of executing the code.

Comment: Ahh I see. I am calling the getDbList() method once in my service and storing it as a static variable. Would this be okay?  Also, how would cache refreshing work? Let's say a entry gets added to the DB, when the time timetoLive expires, would it go execute the query again?

Comment: One more question: when I used @PostConstruct on app start up the result list is not stored in the cache. Any reason why?

Comment: " _I am calling the getDbList() method once in my service and storing it as a static variable. Would this be okay_" - NO, that's not how it's supposed to be used. Instead of storing it in static variable, call getDbList() everwhere where you intended to use that static variable. getDbList() will automatically use EhCache. "_Let's say a entry gets added to the DB, when the time timetoLive expires, would it go execute the query again_" - use @CacheEvict for this purpose. Please read through spring cache abstraction to use it most appropriately.

Comment: "_One more question: when I used PostConstruct on app start up the result list is not stored in the cache. Any reason why?_" -- how and where you used PostConstruct will matter. As mentioned in comments of my answer, PostConstruct will NOT work if used within DbListProvider provider. I'll again advice to study spring cache abstraction to understand it fully and use it most effectively.